# How to upgrade Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac

I am running Mac OS X 10.5.8 presently and want to upgrade to Mac OS X 10.6.3. I have downloaded the update but it's telling me it requires Mac OS X 10.6.

So how do I update from 10.5.8 to 10.6.3?

Comment: +1 (back to zero). I buy and use a lot of Apple products, and without looking at the exact download, I know this is not always labeled clearly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to buy and install OS X 10.6 first.  In general, it is not a free upgrade.

Comment: from where can i get it?

Comment: An Apple store?

Comment: Or Best Buy....

Answer (score 2):

You need to buy `Snow Leopard` (OS X 10.6) from an Apple retailer, Apple Store or from the [Apple Online Store](http://store.apple.com)

Comment: This is an inexpensive upgrade, as Apple upgrades go - $29 from Apple, $25 from Amazon - and well worth doing.  As stated above, be sure your system meets minimum specs: http://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html

Answer (score 2):

You also need to verify that your hardware is supported. Any Mac without an Intel processor will not install 10.6. This means any powermac, powerbook, ibook,  g4 and g5 imacs and g4 mini are not supported.